# does ssh have a facility to exchange files when already connected?

Tags: bash, ssh

I never heard this possible, so probably the answer is not. But maybe someone knows better.

I know you can use `sftp` to exchange files between **host** and **remote**, and you can both: `sftp` from **host** to **remote**, and from **remote** to **host** once you are already connected to the **remote** with `SSH`.

But now my question, once you are connected to the **remote** machine with `SSH` is this possible to transfer files using already established connection? This is so logical, I am already connected, authentication is done, why not just have something like `lls`, `put`. Or use some combination of keys that will bypass remote bash input line and do something between hosts.

Answer (score 5):

Recent versions of OpenSSH support connection multiplexing. Look at the `ControlMaster` and `ControlPath` options for [ssh_config](http://www.manpagez.com/man/5/ssh_config/).

Using this feature, you'd still have to run `scp` or `sftp` to perform a file transfer, but the transfer would run through your existing SSH connection.

Answer (score 2):

You will always need to identify yourself to the machines you are connecting to. You can set it up to work with encrypted keys so no password is needed but the authentication  is still there.

The easiest way to transfer files between remote systems is `scp`, part of the `ssh` package. Lets say your local machine is `1.2.3.4.` and your local user `tom` and the remote machine is `5.6.7.8` and your remote user is `jon`.

- To copy a file from the remote server to your local machine when logged in to the server:

  ```
  scp /home/jon/foo.txt tom@1.2.3.4:/home/tom/
  ```

  Of course, you will still have to identify yourself (to your *local* machine this time). Not, however, to the server.
- To copy a file from the remote server to your local machine when not logged in to the server:

  ```
  scp jon@5.6.7.8:/home/jon/foo.txt /home/tom/
  ```

  This way, you only need to identify yourself once, you don't need to open a separate `ssh` connection.

You can also copy between remote servers, anywhere you have `ssh` access to basically. The general format of the command is

```
scp user1@machine1:/path/to/source user2@machine2/path/to/destination
```

Comment: The OP specifically wanted to reuse the existing SSH connection, not create a new one. How would he use `scp` and the existing connection to move files?

Comment: @DarthAndroid he would not initiate another ssh connection, just use scp, that way only one connection is established. Tongue in cheek, granted, but that's what `scp` is for. Also, I am assuming (perhaps wrongly, the OP may correct me) from the way the question was worded that the OP is not too familiar with `scp` which seems to me to be the most logical choice in the situation described.

Comment: If he's already connected via `ssh`, why does he need to bother with authentication or hosts in `scp` ? If it's just reusing the existing `ssh` connection, isn't he already authenticated and the host doesn't matter? @Kenster found the answer, though I think it needs to be fleshed out a bit more.

Comment: @DarthAndroid with @Kenster's (very good) suggestion won't the OP still need to identify to the local machine? Why not just run `scp` _instead_ of connecting over ssh?

Comment: @terdon because I already connected with ssh many hours ago and keep performing various tasks, now I suddenly need only or few files from my local machine... so the question comes

Comment: @terdon I never used scp, always used sftp, so it was useful, but not what I ask

Answer (score 0):

Using an existing SSH *session*, but not necessarily SSH itself, you could try the trusty classic Zmodem `rz`/`sz`. These utilities may already be available on your system as they are available in RPM and DPKG format in various repos. Otherwise you can download and build them from [here](http://ohse.de/uwe/software/lrzsz.html).